# Simplify $(x'+y)'(x+y)'$ with boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

So I'm doing some homework and trying to simplify $(x'+y)'(x+y)'$. So far these are the steps I've completed, but I'm not 100% sure that they're appropriate.

$(x'+y)'(x+y)' = (x'+y)'(x’y’)$

$(x'+y)'(x’y’) = (x’’+ y’)(x’y’)$

$(x’’+y’)(x’y’) = (x+y’)(x’y’)$

I'm unsure of what to do after this step (or if I've made any actual mistakes)

Comment: use DeMorgan's theorem twice on each term in the product first. Then multiply out and you will have your answer. Truth Tables are not required here.

Answer (score 0):

$(x'+y)'(x+y)'=(x'+y)'(x'y')=(x''y')(x'y')=(xy')(x'y')$

Can you do the last step?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out algebraically so I drew out a truth table to figure it out and realized it was 0.